# dictionary and none within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:
[image]

I would like to modify the column category by implementing the following method : if the dictionary  = None return "NA" (str) else I would like to keep only the value of 'second' (for example EUR in the first line) as a value for the column. Also if the 'second' is None so return "NA".
I tried the following logic : `df['category']= df['category'].apply(lambda x: x['second'] if x is not None)`  but it didn't work as there are some None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'category': [{'first': 'ABC',
                   'second': 'EUR'},
                  {'first': 'ABC',
                   'second': None}]})
df['category'] = df['category'].str['second'].fillna('NA')
```

Using `.str['second']` it will try to get the 'second' key from the dictionaries if available. If this is not available, it will return `None` (or `NaN` if for example an integer is included in the column). The final `.fillna('NA')` is used to convert these values to `'NA'`.

Output:

```
  category
0      EUR
1       NA
```

Comment: According to the OP you should use `fillna('NA')`

Comment: it doesn't seem very flexible if I add a bunch of rows with different dictionaries.

Comment: If you add something different from a dictionary with key 'second', it will return 'NA'

Comment: Indeed I didn't see that you recreated a dataframe only with 2 lines so I though it was wrong ! Thanks

Comment: .str['second'].fillna('NA') can you detail how this work please ? From what I understand it converts the value associated to the key 'second' into str or fill NA if None but can you detail for my knowledge please ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `'NA' if x is None else` to your lambda expression to check for `None` first:

```
df['category'] = df['category'].apply(lambda x: 'NA' if x is None else #check for None
                     x['second'] if x['second'] is not None else 'NA') #check for second
```